# Combining env variables with strings in settings

Tags: craft3

I have a site with multiple subsites in the following structure:
`www.site.domain/subsite`.

To create multiple subsites, I'd consider setting a base url in the .env (for easy changes: localhost <> live url) and setting the url for each subsite like this `$SITE_URL . 'subsite-string'`.

Is there any way to achieve this? Or is the only way a full variable per subsite like `$SITE_URL_SUBSITE_STRING`?

Comment: [Give this a read](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/asset-volume-using-environment-variable-on-file-system-path-as-literal-string-on/30733#30733). Aliases might be the way.

Comment: Just what I needed, perfect. If you mind adding that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted for anyone else with the same question.